# Gradient of a Function defined on a polygonal surface

Tags: vector-analysis, polygons

I have a convex polygon defined in a 3-D space. Such polygon has a variable number of vertices, since it is generated by a Voronoi Diagram.
I know the values of a function on the vertices, and I would like to compute the gradient of such function at a point contained in the surface (namely its center of mass). 
Now, I know there is a very simple formula for this calculation if the polygon is a triangle (http://dgd.service.tu-berlin.de/wordpress/vismathws10/2012/10/17/gradient-of-scalar-functions/), I am wondering if it is possible to extend such idea to polygons with number of vertices greater than 3.

Comment: In the cited formula, the function $g$ is linear, which is an important assumption in the derivation of the formula. Is your function linear?

Comment: Short answer: yes Long answer: the function is thought to be linear with the Finite Element Method in mind, where the response function on a triangular element is usually interpolated by linear functions defined on the surface. We accept errors in the calculated gradient, and we obtain the required accuracy by increasing the number of sampling points, i.e. the number of finite elements.